# CDI ApplicationScoped threadsafe?

Tags: jsf, jakarta-ee, cdi

Pretty basic question, but I couldn't find a clear answer anywhere.

When I have an `@ApplicationScoped` bean where I store state (application scoped cache), do I have to handle synchronization when changing/accessing the fields by hand, or does CDI handle it for me as e.g. EJB does?

Comment: This one has been answered here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14237499/jee6-applicationscoped-bean-and-concurrency